# Registry keys deleted in Windows 10 regedit.exe appear again if regedit.exe is started by another application

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I've been tweaking loading times of directory contents in Windows Explorer of Windows 10 and I have deleted some of the keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers`.

So far so good. But I have as well an application which can start `regedit.exe` on demand.

And when `regedit.exe` is started by this application, all deleted keys are in their former places. If I start `regedit.exe` manually, those keys are not present.

Question, does this application open `regedit.exe` with some different account and registry hive I'm seeing is not hive of my user profile?

If not, then what causes this ghostly effect?

Comment: is the application a 32bit application and is actually looking at the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node` node?

Comment: *facepalm* Actually, yes, it is 32bit application. I should be more attentive. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation where it seems there are two different versions of the registry can occur on 64bit Windows machines. There is the normal SOFTWARE node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
```

and there is a second one for 32bit applications

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node
```

All reads and changes done by any 32bit application are done against the `WOW6432Node`. Using `regedit.exe` manually, you will usually look directly under `SOFTWARE`. But you can open the `WOW6432Node` node as well.